# Recurring "Can't connect to MySQL server .. Temporary failure in name resolution" in GKE cluster

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I deployed MySQL server using `mysql:5.7` image on my GKE cluster. Its deployed with one replica and exposed with a ClusterIP service named "mysql-server".

In the last few hours I'm experiencing recurring flaky errors from other pods that are running Python servers:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql-server' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)")`

I've gone over [Kubernetes DNS debugging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) and found no errors or other issues, except for CoreDNS not running at all in any of my clusters.

When executing `nslookup mysql-server` on another pod, I'm getting an healthy output.

```
Server:     10.39.240.10
Address:    10.39.240.10#53

Name:   mysql-server.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.39.245.88
```

However, `ping mysql-server` never returns, don't know if its relevant.

```
PING mysql-server.default.svc.cluster.local (10.39.245.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- mysql-server.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2039ms
```

Would this be an issue on mysql or GKE? How can I debug it further?

Comment: Best relevant issue I could find: https://itamargero.com/rds-intermittent-connection-issues-solved/ , don't see if it can be applied to GKE